# Play background music outside of app bundle using SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I need to play background music residing in the app's document folder (using hosted content downloads which I put in the document folder after download).

It seems that SimpleAudioEngine's way of playing background music is to take a relative path and find it inside the app bundle (CDAudioManager does it):

```
@"mysong.mp3"
```

becomes

```
@"...19E17B5B/myapp.app/mysong.mp3"
```

Which is not helpful because the file saved into the Documents folder looks like this

```
@"...19E17B5B/Documents/mysong.mp3"
```

Edit: It works by specifying something like this @"../Documents/mysong.mp3"

However as we know this would not be recommended/future proof... Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by specifying a relative path like this `@"../Documents/mysong.mp3"`, totally ignoring all recommended ways to get paths :-P

Comment: Somehow I think this actually broke recently... doh. CDAudioManager needs fixing??